# Making Jenkins localhost publicly available within the same network

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-job-dsl

I am running my jenkins on localhost on my macmini which is my remote machine. All the tests are also running on that mac mini. However i want to share that localhost:8080 jenkins url to make it publickly so something like the eg.71.65.187.98:8080. so within the same network my coworkers can open the url and see the jenkins. How can i do that? without using any external service?

Answer (score 0):

Run `ifconfig` in the terminal. it'll show all the network interfaces on your Mac. One of them is the network your machine is actively connected to.

If your Mac is on a wired connection that should be `en0`. Make a note of the address after `inet`, that should be the address your machine uses

Comment: i got it but do i need to add that IP in the jenkins setting? Because i tried to access the IPaddress:8080 and it is not found

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you start your jenkins server. If you use the generic war file then you can add the command flags `--httpPort=yourPort --httpListenAddress=yourAdress`.
A complete command could look like this:

```sh
java "${JAVA_OPTS}" -Xms256m -Xmx256m -jar jenkins.war --httpPort=8787 --httpListenAddress=192.168.0.171
```

Depending on your OS it may be possible that you need to tell your firewall to open the desired port.

Comment: not sure if it will work i start my jenkins using - brew services start jenkins-lts

Comment: In case you installed Jenkins via and package manager it is very likely that you have a global config file wäre you can set the desired value for `httpListenAddress`. According to this blog post it could be `/usr/local/opt/jenkins-lts/homebrew.mxcl.jenkins-lts.plist`  
https://www.macminivault.com/installing-jenkins-on-macos/

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the issue since i installed my jenkins using brew. first I needed to :

1. `nano /usr/local/opt/jenkins-lts/homebrew.mxcl.jenkins-lts.plist`
2. then change the httpListenAddress to `0.0.0.0`
3. Then by using ifconfig on the terminal i was able to get my IP address and i was able the use `IP address:8080` inside my network.